# How to set notifications on selected date and time in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I already know how to create notifications . My problem is that i have to click a button for it to pop up in the status bar. What i want is that the notifications pop up based on user selected time and date. I have time picker and date picker in the layout. I want to use this method for like a reminder app. To remind the users of the tasks.

Do you know how? I tried to search some notes in Google. I couldn't find any. All of the Codes i found for the problem has this function -> notifications.setLatestEventInfo() and this function wont work. It wont recognize the function. So it doesn't help solve my problem.

I would appreciate it greatly if you could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are missing is Alarm Manager. This class allows you to schedule some events, like notifcation. Below you have full documentation about alarm manager:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

And the example implementation:

http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/android-sdk-add-a-repeating-alarmmanager-to-the-autostart-displaying-messages-in-the-notification-bar/

Comment: btw, if i turn off the phone, would it still alarm?

Comment: If you have your phone turned off, it won't notify. Btw take a look on Wakeful Broadcast receiver. This will enable waking up the device when notification is about to occure.

Comment: do i have to make a database for this? for the selected time and date

Comment: No you don't unless you want to store this data.

Comment: the note you gave me wont work. i put in the question. please no setLatestEventInfo function cause that function is not recognize in the Android Studio. i guess im back to square one.